# How to add multiple rows in different multiple sections in tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have tableview in that cell I have created header view in that header I have label and button, I am getting label values from array and that array counts number of sections which works fine. but when I tap on button I need to expand cell and in that expanded cell I need to add label but while I am tapping button it says

> error: Index out of range

in `numberOfRowsInSection` and it is not expanded.

here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, DataSendingDelegateProtocol, FieldsDelegateProtocol {
var shouldCellBeExpanded:Bool = false
var indexOfExpendedCell:NSInteger = -1
// let kHeaderSectionTag: Int = 6900;

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var sectionArray = [String]()
var sectionItemsArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //self.tableView!.tableFooterView = UIView()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func sendDataToTableRow(myData: String) {
    self.sectionItemsArray.append(myData)
    tableView.reloadData()
   // print(iteamsArray)
}

func sendDataToSectionLabel(myData: String) {
    self.sectionArray.append(myData)
    tableView.reloadData()
    print(sectionArray)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segue") {
        let vc = segue.destination as! PopViewController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "fieldsSegue") {
        let vc = segue.destination as! FieldsViewController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
@objc func expandButnClicked(sender:UIButton){

    print("expand button tapped")

    shouldCellBeExpanded = !shouldCellBeExpanded
    indexOfExpendedCell = sender.tag

    if shouldCellBeExpanded {

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    else {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

@IBAction func addBtn(_ sender: Any) {
}

// MARK: - Tableview Methods
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return sectionArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (self.indexOfExpendedCell == section) {
        let arrayOfItems = self.sectionItemsArray[section]
        return arrayOfItems.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if (self.sectionArray.count != 0) {
        return self.sectionArray[section] as? String
    }
    return ""
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0;
}

/*func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    return 0;
}*/

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(hexStr: "#0075d4")
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 380, y: 10, width: 15, height: 15))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    button.tag = section
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandButnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    header.addSubview(button)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if shouldCellBeExpanded && indexPath.row == indexOfExpendedCell {
        return 200
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.textLab?.textColor = UIColor.black
    cell.textLab.text = sectionItemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
}
```

Please help me in the code.

Comment: add new  index in sectionItemsArray , on button Tap..

Comment: @RajeshKumarR no different sectionItemsArray for different cells

Comment: @RajeshKumarR sectionItemsArray data will come from sendDataToTableRow delegate method

Comment: sectionItemsArray type should be `[[String]]`. For ex: `var sectionArray: [String] = ["1","2"]
var sectionItemsArray:[[String]] = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]`

Comment: @RajeshKumarR  ["a", "b", "c"] var sectionArray: [String] = ["1","2"]

Comment: i want these three in one section i mean which section i tap in that section i want sectionItemsArray

Comment: @RajeshKumarR  i want same functionality should be repeat for all sections, is there any mistake in numberofsections

Answer (score 0):

If section is expanded return sectionItemsArray array count in numberOfRowsInSection method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.indexOfExpendedCell == section) {
        return self.sectionItemsArray.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: i got same error    here return self.sectionItemsArray.count error: Index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be pinpointed to 2 methods you implemented:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return sectionArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (self.indexOfExpendedCell == section) {
        let arrayOfItems = self.sectionItemsArray[section]
        return arrayOfItems.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

In the first one you explain how many sections you have for which you used `sectionArray` but then in the second you use another array `sectionItemsArray`. Your crash is most likely in case of `sectionItemsArray[sectionArray.count-1]` which will fail when `sectionItemsArray` has fewer number of elements than `sectionArray`.

You should probably have this consistent and use only one array. In your case it makes sense to use array of arrays to represent sections and rows. But in general it might be better to use custom structures. Consider something like the following:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    class Section {
        class Row {
            let name: String
            var shown: Bool = true
            init(name: String) { self.name = name }
        }
        let name: String
        var shown: Bool = true
        var rows: [Row]

        init(name: String, rows: [Row] = [Row]()) { self.name = name; self.rows = rows }
    }

    var sections: [Section]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sections = [
            Section(name: "Empty"),
            Section(name: "Second section", rows: [.init(name: "row 1"), .init(name: "row 2")]),
            Section(name: "Third section", rows: [.init(name: "row 1"), .init(name: "row 2")])
        ]
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.filter { $0.shown }.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections.filter { $0.shown }[section].name
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections.filter { $0.shown }[section].rows.filter { $0.shown }.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let name: String = sections.filter { $0.shown }[indexPath.section].rows.filter { $0.shown }[indexPath.row].name
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: sectionArray.count for number of section, and sectionItemsArray for number of rows but got error in  let arrayOfItems = self.sectionItemsArray[section]

Comment: @Swift Seems incorrect. The array you use count from must be the same you later access to get additional data. Did you mean something like `sectionCount = sectionArray.count` and then `rowCount = sectionArray[section].count`. Anyway your data source does not seem to be setup like that.